# Elasticsearch binary field type, does it return in hits?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've read the elasticsearch docs on the binary field, but am having a hard time understanding what they mean. Will an elasticsearch query return a binary field type? I understand it is not searchable, which I interpret as meaning I can't filter on it, but would it return in the hits of a query based on ID for example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should return in response and it will be available inside `_source`.

You can just use below command in kibana dev tool and check it.

```
GET index_name/_search
```

```json
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Some binary blob",
          "blob" : "U29tZSBiaW5hcnkgYmxvYg=="
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```